# A good differentiation problem

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

[image]

Could anyone please help with the simplification? or highlight short tricks, if any? It'd be great help. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Just change variable $y=\frac1z$ culculate $y', y'', y''$ put in the given expression then after some calculus it must be the same but with variable z and  derivatives of z.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{1}{y}'=-\frac{1}{y^2}y'$$
For rest, further diffrenciate it to get

$$\frac{1}{y}''=-\frac{1}{y^2}y''+(\frac{2}{y^3})y'$$

and so on..

Comment: Oh! Is that the only way? Won't that get too long? I was looking for some easy simplification

Comment: Yes, and I have verified this before answer - it is not so long. I do not think there is a workaround.

Comment: Could you check the other solution (the other comment), and point out the mistake? or maybe post a solution? Thanks again

Comment: Shoukd the second term have $y'^2$

Answer (score 1):

$$S=\frac{y'''}{y'}-\frac{3}{2}\cdot \left(\frac{y''}{y'}\right)^2,\quad y'=\frac{dy}{dx}$$

Let $u = \frac{1}{y}\implies \frac{du}{dx} = -\frac{1}{y^2}\cdot\frac{dy}{dx}\implies u'=-u^2y'\implies y'=-\frac{1}{u^2}u'$

$\implies u'' = -2u\frac{du}{dx}\cdot y' -u^2\cdot y'' = 2u^3(y')^2-u^2y'' =2u^3\cdot \frac{1}{u^4}\cdot (u')^2-u^2y''$

$\implies u'' =  \frac{2}{u}(u')^2-u^2y''\implies y'' = \frac{2}{u^3}(u')^2-\frac{1}{u^2}u''$

$\implies u''' =6u^2(y')^2\cdot u' +2u^3\cdot 2y'\cdot y'' -2uu'y''-u^2\cdot y'''$

$\implies u''' = 6u^2\cdot\frac{1}{u^4}\cdot (u')^3+4u^3\cdot (-\frac{1}{u^2}u')(\frac{2}{u^3}(u')^2-\frac{1}{u^2}u'')-2uu'(\frac{2}{u^3}(u')^2-\frac{1}{u^2}u'')-u^2y'''$

$\implies u''' =\frac{6}{u^2}(u')^3+\frac{4u'}{u}(u''-2\frac{(u')^2}{u})-\frac{4}{u^2}(u')^3+\frac{2u'u''}{u}-u^2y'''$

$\implies u'''= \frac{2}{u^2}(u')^3+\frac{6u'u''}{u}-\frac{8(u')^3}{u^2}-u^2y''' =\frac{6u'u''}{u}-\frac{6(u')^3}{u^2} -u^2y'''$

$\implies y''' = \frac{1}{u^2}\left(-u'''+\frac{6u'u''}{u}-\frac{6(u')^3}{u^2}\right)$

Then $$S= \frac{\frac{1}{u^2}\left(-u'''+\frac{6u'u''}{u}-\frac{6(u')^3}{u^2}\right)}{-\frac{1}{u^2}u'}-\frac{3}{2}\cdot \left(\frac{\frac{2}{u^3}(u')^2-\frac{1}{u^2}u''}{-\frac{1}{u^2}u'}\right)^2 $$

$$S = \frac{u'''}{u'}-6\frac{u''}{u}+6\left(\frac{u'}{u}\right)^2-\frac{3}{2}\left(-2\frac{u'}{u}+\frac{u''}{u}\right)^2$$

$$\require{cancel}S = \frac{u'''}{u'}-6\frac{u''}{u}+\cancel{6\left(\frac{u'}{u}\right)^2}-\frac{3}{2}\left(\cancel{4\left(\frac{u'}{u}\right)^2}+\left(\frac{u''}{u}\right)^2-4\frac{u'u''}{u^2}\right)$$

I made a mistake somewhere, but it's late and I have made so much latex that I can't bring myself to just delete the answer. I have posted as community wiki in the hopes that a good Samaritan will come along and correct the answer. :)